# ERROR: unknown command "authtoken" for "ngrok"

Tags: cmd, ngrok

Can't register ngrok auth token because command authtoken is unknown.
im using widows.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get your ngrok binary from?

Comment: it's from official.
well i was solve the problem by adding ngrok.yml manually at path
`C://Users/<My Device>/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml`
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ngrok authtoken TOKEN_VALUE
```

works on windows, just ensure to add or have an `ngrok.yml` present in the `C://Users/<My Device>/.ngrok2/` directory

Comment: it works on ubuntu as well ! thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use this command

`ngrok config add-authtoken TOKEN_VALUE`

Comment: Someone needs to update the install instructions for Linux on their website, it doesn't download a zip (downloads a .tar.gz) and the command line to add the authtoken doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @SteveChilds, we will take a look!

Comment: ```ngrok config add-authtoken TOKEN_VALUE```

Doesn't work on windows either:


```Unrecognized command: config```

Comment: did anyone find a solution for windows?

Answer (score 0):

I originally had the same error message of Unrecognized command: config on kali linux. Using `./ngrok authtoken TOKEN_VAUE` seems to work